# Append aiArealights in list naming convection in maya with Python

Tags: maya

So I have a fucntion, When I click on a button , there is an aiAreaLight appening in my list. 
 I rename the lights to 'PainterLight_aiArealight'+'1', so every time I make a light I have this name with 1,2,3 ect...

In My outliner I have the correct name , but when i print my List, it keeps the name 'transform1.

Can someone explain me what I do wrong ?

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpszw.jpg)

My code :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
lights=[]
def Button_pressed ():
    lights.append(cmds.shadingNode('aiAreaLight', asLight=True))
    cmds.rename(lights[len(lights)-1],'PainterLight_aiArealight'+'1')
    print(lights)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maya.cmds usually work with strings. So your list of lights is indeed a list of strings and has no connection to any real object in maya. In this case you can either simply first rename your light and then append it to your list, or you can use pymel which uses objects and works with renaming.

```
import pymel.core as pm
lights=[]
def Button_pressed ():
    lights.append(pm.shadingNode('aiAreaLight', asLight=True))
    lights[-1].rename('PainterLight_aiArealight'+'1')
    print(lights)
```